# Debug WebStorm not provided

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I tried to debug my JavaScript but the tools to step into code is not enabled:
[image]

And in Chrome browser I've installed JetBrains' extension:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205988304-Debug-webstorm-not-provided

Answer (score 0):

Try again.. Since WebStorm 2017.3 you can now use Chrome DevTools and WebStorm debugger at the same time. You no longer need an additional Chrome extension to debug apps in WebStorm.

Read about it in [Debugging JavaScript with WebStorm 2017.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/debugging-javascript-with-webstorm-2017-3/)